# Excel 2013 connect to SQL Server - run SQL on table?

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-2013

I need to display a quite subset of data from an SQL Server table in Excel. I need users to be able to open the Excel sheet periodically, and click something to refresh the data.

This subset of data is from one very large table but I am only interested in a few records and have the SQL to select these.  I do not want every record from the table in my Excel spreadsheet.

I do not have access to the SQL server directly but do have a machine ODBC connection to the database and credentials to access data.

So I can create a linked table in MS Access easily enough, and then run the query there and export it to Excel, but I really need something in Excel so that other people without Access can use it.

Now, in Excel 2013, I can connect to the SQL Server database using the Wizard (Data - From SQL Server - Data Connection Wizard), the credentials I have work, etc. But then it wants you to select a table. Now the table itself is huge and I'm worried that if I continue through this Wizard, it'll import everything from the whole table into my s/sheet, which is not what I want.  So I've quit out because I cannot risk performance issues on the database.

How can I make it so it only runs a query on the table and shows only the results in Excel?  I've never used PivotTables but again I'm concerned it'll try and download everything in that table whilst trying to do that.

I'm aware of the very old MS Query functionality, but I thought this was not really used anymore?

Comment: You can write the query directly in the `Definitions` tab that appears when you click Data>Connections>Properties. You can also use`MS Query`. As far as I can tell the result is the same for an ODBC connection.

Comment: Also you can install PowerQuery for free.

Comment: The Access Runtime, for viewing queries and tables, is a free download from Microsoft for all versions of office.https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=10910

Comment: @DougGlancy do I need to amend 'Command Type' from 'Table' to 'SQL' and then put the SQL in the 'Command Text' field?

Comment: Ben, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy, if you follow after **The Choose Data Source** dialog box is displayed you must click the **Queries** tab.

Double-click the saved query that you want to open. The query is displayed in Microsoft Query.